# Where can I get apt GPG Public keys for older release

Tags: apt

I would like to install a [package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/libtiff4) from an older ubuntu release into a install of a new ubuntu release, in my case 20.04.

I've added the apt sources list:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main universe
deb [trusted=yes] http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main universe
```

This works, and I can install the package, but I would like to remove the `[trusted=yes]` and actually verify the packages being downloaded.

Where can I find the gpg public keys for older releases (specifically precise), that I can use with `apt-key add`?

Answer (score 1):

One can find the public keys from the [ubuntu-keyring](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/ubuntu-keyring) package.

However this will not solve the issue as the keys have all expired, and the verification will fail for this reason.